# Trying to get multiple records from database using OOP class

Tags: php, mysql, oop

So I followed a tutorial on how to create a login system in OOP. Now, I'm using multiple databases on the same MySQL server. I would like to get records from all databases when I need to.

The problem is, I don't now how to go about this.

**I have the following code:**

```
public function __construct($user = null) {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

        $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');

        if(!$user) {
            if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
                $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

                if($this->find('users', $user)) {
                    $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
                    //$this->find('digi_settings.settings_pin', $user);
                } else {
                    // process logout
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->find($user);
        }
    }
```

I commented out my added line of code. My line should get the information from the `digi_settings` database and `settings_pin` table.

This all works fine, but when I try to get information from the original database and table (which is `digi_users.users`) it won't show that, but only the information from the `digi_settings` database.

So for example, `echo $user->data()->active === 'yes' ? 'checked' : ''` would work fine, but `echo escape($user->data()->username);` wouldn't.

In this example, `active` is a row in the `digi_settings.settings_pin` database and table, and `username` is a row in the `digi_users.users` database and table.

**I'm using the following code to find a user:**

```
public function find($table, $user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get($table, array($field, '=', $user));

            if($data->count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

public function data() {
        return $this->_data;
    }
```

**I have a feeling that the issue I'm having has something to do with this line of code:**

```
if($data->count()) {
          $this->_data = $data->first();
          return true;
}
```

I've looked at some other examples, but those didn't help me much.

Any hints or tips are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: what framework do you use? The answer is probably in its doc.

Comment: @Asenar I really got it figured out, thanks!